# Android Testing AsyncTask with TextView Passed in

Tags: android, android-asynctask, mocking, android-testing

I have an AsyncTask that I would like to write a test for.  It has a TextView that is passed in:

```
public LoadAssetTask(TextView target, boolean skipSingleLineBreak, InputStream in) { ...}
```

How do I write an Adroid JUnit test for this?  Is there a way to use a Mock Object to Mock an activity with a text field, I'd hate to create a whole activity or use one that is already since I want to test just this class.  I tried using a mock activity but you have to add that to the manifest and I don't want to do that for each and every AsyncTask that I have.

Comment: ummm... are you are passing a TextView into doInBackground?  I smell smoke...

Comment: LOL its fine passing it in so that I can set it when done executing.  Similar to progress bars and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2? This class runs JUnit tests for methods in another Activity. In fact, it's the *only* way to run a JUnit test against a method in an Activity (or methods in a contained class of an Activity). AsyncTask has to run within an Android context (because it uses Android thread APIs), but I assume that ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 can communicate with any thread in the process.

Documentation for ActivitInstrumentationTestCase2 is at http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

Comment: Right but does this create a mock activity, which is what I am looking for.  I want to avoid the garbage that comes with a gui and just mock one up and fire off the asynctask.